# Expression expected Intellij Jav

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok, faker

This is my Person Class, with a Gender enum, I'm Using Lombok to generate data, constructors and builder function.

```java
public class Person {

        public enum Gender {
            FEMALE, MALE;
        }

        private int id;
        private String name;
        private LocalDate birthDate;
        private Gender gender;
        private String email;
        private String phone;
        private String profession;
        private boolean married;
    }
```

I'm trying to create a function that returns a Person Object using the builder function with fake generated data using [Java Faker](https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker)

```java
static Person createPerson(){
        Faker faker = new Faker();
        LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.ofInstant(faker.date().birthday().toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
        return  Person.builder()
                .id(1)
                .name(faker.name().fullName())
                .birthDate(birthday)
                .gender(faker.options().option(Person.Gender))
                .email(faker.internet().emailAddress())
                .phone(faker.phoneNumber().phoneNumber())
                .profession(faker.company().profession())
                .married(faker.bool().bool());
    }
```

It shows an error "Expression Expected" when trying to pass in the Gender enum to get a random element using the Options.option() from Java Faker. Here's the exact line.

```java
.gender(faker.options().option(Person.Gender))
```

Can you please help me!

Comment: `Person.Gender.class` should do the trick (taken from [their tests](https://github.com/DiUS/java-faker/blob/master/src/test/java/com/github/javafaker/OptionsTest.java#L40))

Comment: you need to pass Gender.MALE or Gender.FEMALE  that is .gender(faker.options().option(Gender.MALE))

Comment: @sanjeevRm I thought so as well, but [that method expects a `Class`](http://dius.github.io/java-faker/apidocs/com/github/javafaker/Options.html#option-java.lang.Class-)